# Mongoose -> findOne -> sort -> if there is no records in DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have issue with middleware method in nodeJS.
In this method, I am looking for one album, which has highest custom ID property, and after sort and picking up highest value, I make an increment ++.

Everything is working ok, but issue comes into stage, when no records in DB.

What I want do is make a default `album.id = 1` when there is no records.

My code:

```
// ID MIDDLEWARE
newID.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var _newAlbumID;
    Album.findOne().sort('-id').exec(function (err, album, newID) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            var test = ++album.id;
            _newAlbumID = test;
            console.log("IN: ", test, _newAlbumID);
            req.body.id = _newAlbumID;
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for help and hints.

Answer (score 1):

Just test `album` for non-empty.

```
Album.findOne().sort('-id').exec(function (err, album, newID) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else if (!album) {
        ...
        ...
        }
    else {
        var test = ++album.id;
        _newAlbumID = test;
        console.log("IN: ", test, _newAlbumID);
        req.body.id = _newAlbumID;
        next();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, my fault, - it's obviously gives an error, because no album record is available. But you've got a clue.

Answer (score 0):

That was good point. I'v done that with:

```
else if (!album) {
            _newAlbumID = 1;
            req.body.id = _newAlbumID;
            console.log("NO ALBUM");
            next();
        }
```

I cant make assign `album.id = 1`, when there is no any album in query:)